# What is the best way to close a dropdown in zurb foundation 4 when clicking on a link?

Tags: performance, zurb-foundation

When clicking on a link in a zurb foundation 4 dropdown, the link does not close the drop down.
What is the best way to do this systematically across the site?

I have created the following function to solve this problem.
Is this the best way to do it, or am I missing something?

```
 $('.f-dropdown').click(function(){
     if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
         $('span[data-dropdown="'+$(".f-dropdown").attr('id')+'"]').trigger('click');
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably already corrected it in your own code but it will work better this way if you have more than one dropdown on your webpage:

```
$('.f-dropdown').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('open')) {
         $('span[data-dropdown="'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').trigger('click');
     }
});
```

Comment: I have the same problem and I also noticed zurb-foundation document page examples where the split buttons are show also work the same way.  They do not close, is this a zurb bug?

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/split-buttons.html

I also tried to build the dropdown content via select-option tags, they also work the same way.  after selection the dropdown stays open.

Comment: Is there no way to make this work without JQuery?  I have an angularjs/foundation combination and would like to avoid jQuery if possible

Comment: This is technically not a zurb bug, because zurb is assuming I am not using this for a single page app. I actually am using this with angularjs. I ended up creating a custom directive, so i can use it when needed in my angularjs app.

Answer (score 0):

You also need the data-dropdown-content attribute attached to the dropdown ul element.

Reference: https://github.com/zurb/foundation/issues/1831#issuecomment-15133817

Answer (score 0):

I use this to change the behavior of all dropdown buttons in a page in zurb foundation 3.2.5. Haven't tested it in 4, but as it's a different method here it goes.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('.button.dropdown').find('li').click(function () {
            $(this).parents('.button.dropdown')[0].click();
        });
    });
```